# How to return value after all promise in React and Firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, promise, firebase-storage

I'm making web site using react based on Firebase. Recently, I met some problem about getting url of storage.
Below is my codes.

```
(state, action) => {
  const snapshot = action.payload;
  const list = [];

  snapshot.forEach((child) => {
    list.push({
      key: child.key,
      user_bg_url: child.val().user_bg_url,
      user_hp: child.val().user_hp,
      user_id: child.val().user_id,
      user_img_url: child.val().user_img_url,
      user_login_yn: child.val().user_login_yn,
      user_msg_block: child.val().user_msg_block,
      user_token: child.val().user_token,
    });
  });

  list.forEach(async (user) => {
    await storage.getUserImage(user.user_img_url).then((url) => {
      user.user_img_url = url;
    });
  })

  return state.setIn(['users', 'list'], list);
}
```

---

```
getUserImage: (gs_url) => {
  return storage.refFromURL(gs_url).getDownloadURL();
},
```

I want to return value after work of 'list.forEach'. But it just return blank array before completion of 'list.forEach'.

Comment: use .map instead, thus creating an array of promises that you can then wait on.

Answer (score 2):

You're correct that `return` is getting called before your `forEach` completes, so you'll need to return a promise. Using `Promise.all()` and `map` would work here.

```
return Promise.all(list.map(async (user) => {
  await storage.getUserImage(user.user_img_url).then((url) => {
    user.user_img_url = url;
  });
})).then(() => {
  return state.setIn(['users', 'list'], list);
});
```

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37576787/4816918).

Comment: Answer thanks, Jeff. But this answer did not return value I want.

Comment: Because I used specific function getting state for convenience about then() of promise. So, if return value is function, it is not given to specific  function. So the origin code return just state.

Comment: Looks like you're using redux here. Usually reducers like your function don't do anything asynchronous because they need to return the state object. Look into using asynchronous actions (http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html) to do the asynchronous stuff, and only call the reducers when you have the results you need.

Comment: The function I mentioned was using redux-promise-middleware... However, I solved this problem as setting state of the component that it is used from the result excepted 'list.forEach'.